# The Address and Search Windows, in Windows Explorer following a recenWindows Update, will not resize

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

My Win 7 Pro 64 Bit SP 1. 
The normal solution (From a Previous Answer to the top of the list Questions Above -  "Unable to resize Windows 7 Search box in Windows Explorer" ) to moving The Bar between the Address and Search Windows, in Windows Explorer no longer works following a recent Windows Update...
Is there a Registry Key to (Lock/Unlock) Size arrows to Change the Size of the Windows 7 “Windows Explorer” Address and Search Bar Windows? Or another fix for this annoying problem?

Comment: WHen did it work last?  Did you change screen resolutions? Themes, reg settings?   Or just give up and use voidtools, Everything.exe

Comment: Hi @PGCGull, this is commonly known as a "wall of text".. you should apply better formatting so that your question is easily readable.  You can see what it will look like in the preview pane just below the area you are editing.

Answer (score 0):

Was that a recent update or the one that was later fixed on Patch Tuesday in 2011?

Open Computer, click Organize>Layout>Menu bar to expose the menu bar. Then right click the open space next to "Help", and uncheck "Lock the toolbars". Now, you can resize the search box by grabbing the bar just to the left of it, but to the right of the circular arrows.

No good?